# How to cut the non-overlapping part of 2 shapes in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I have 2 shapes (see below) a circle and a shape of the US. I want to remove the part of the US that falls outside the circle. How is this possible?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question specifically (no "cutting" involved), but another less-permanent way to do this is with a clipping mask. Duplicate the circle and make sure it is above the art you want to remove.

Then, select both the circle and the art, and do **Object** → **Clipping Mask** → **Make**.

This will just "hide" the portion that you don't want to appear without actually cutting the artwork.

#### Before:

[image: Before]

#### After

[image: After]

If you view the Outlines, you can see the rest of North America is still there, just hidden.

[image: Hidden Eastern Seaboard]

<sup>Side note: the Hawaii on your map is HUGE. ;)</sup>

Comment: Yep, this is the way I'd do it. Scott's answer really *removes* the art; I'm a packrat and tend to prefer to hide things rather than destroy them.

Comment: Much nicer way of doing it thanks. Yeah, Hawaii is way too big and the distance from the mainland is wrong too but wanted to emphasize it as much as possible. Thanks again.

Comment: This isn't the same question. And saying "duplicate the circle" isn't as good an explanation of the options. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37007/

Answer (score 5):

Draw a shape which covers the area you want to remove.

Select the new path and the continent. On the Pathfinder Panel (Window > Pathfinder), click the Minus Front button.