# How to cut off overlapping outlines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So I'm trying to make graphics on a snowboard on illustrator and some of the artwork goes outside of the outline of the snowboard.  I'm wondering if there is a way that I could cut off the excess lines besides using the direct selection tool.

Comment: Have you tried using the [pathfinder tool](http://sites.duke.edu/oit-mps/2010/12/14/using-the-pathfinder-tool-in-adobe-illustrator/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to cut the non-overlapping part of 2 shapes in Illustrator CS6](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18488/8708)

Comment: Make sure the outline of the snowboard includes the bleed, otherwise you're just gonna end up redrawing part of what you're trying to remove for purely aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 3):

**Non-destructive:** Clipping mask. That's my pick

**Destructive:** Expand any effects and use the Pathfinder or Scissors to remove your unwanted vectors.

**Lazy:** Just indicate the object boundaries (the board) with a dieline and leave everything where it is.

Comment: Depends on the day.