# Create layer in another layer borders

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, shapes, illustration, borders

I am using adobe Illustrator CC 2018.
I have a circle and I want to create a rectangle inside the circle without getting outside of the circle borders.

[image: Get rid of the selected parts]

(Delete selected parts)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Danielillo I don’t think it’s a duplicate at all.  As I read this question, Omer is looking for how to inscribe a rectangle.  I think dragging from the center of the circle to draw the rectangle while holding down the Alt key is all that is needed.

Comment: @Wildcard I see, I read it wrong

Comment: ill add a comment with pic and it will be more clear

Comment: @Danielillo I added an image

Comment: Ok, I go back to the duplicate I putted before https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18488/120647

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw the circle and square then select both shapes. Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if you need to keep these shapes after the next step.
2. Open up the 'Window → Pathfinder' panel and click the 'Intersect' button. This will permanently damage both original shapes, but you can now bring them back by doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (paste in place).

[image]

Comment: Not what I meant but thank you,

Comment: I added a image to explain

Comment: Use exclude instead of intersect on the pathfinder panel, then ungroup the resulting shape and delete the bits that you don't want.